# java linux terminal -cp auto-complete

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, autocomplete, terminal

I'm working with a java library which needs two files 'library.jar' and 'library-extensions.jar'. Whenever I try to include both of them separated by a colon (e.g. -cp "library.jar:library-extensions.jar") and try to use auto-complete on the second jar file, it substitutes the first argument for the second one.

i.e.

I have something like this:

```
java -cp "library.jar:l
```

I press 'Tab' to auto-complete the second argument and it changes to:

```
java -cp "l
```

Is there anything I can do to enable proper auto-complete on additional arguments?

I'm using terminal on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on askubuntu.com?

Comment: @fge actually, he wants to autocomplete arguments... i guess it may fit in SO also, but maybe askubuntu users will know this feature deeper than us

Comment: @fge, sorry I'm new to SO, I'm not sure what the boundaries are for SO content. If this content belongs on askubuntu.com, then I would be more than happy if a mod can move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using double quotes (") which is causing you problem.

Remove double quotes & auto-complete will work easily :)